# Windows 10 external monitor image noisy

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, windows-10

Since I upgraded my Dell Studio XPS 16 (ATI mobility Radeon HD 4670) to Win 10, the external monitor shows a noisy image after power up.
If I pull the Display Port connector and reinsert it, the nopise is gone. Noise is primarily vertical lines.
When I dual boot into Linux (same resolution 1980x1200), there is no problem with the image quality.

Answer (score 0):

Attach another external monitor.  If the lines show there, it a graphics card problem.  If they don't, its a monitor problem.I have suffered the same issue and seems to be a common complaint.

Comment: I am convinced, it is a Win 10 (driver) issue, as it works flawlessly in Windows 7 and Linux